# When call controller_name.classify.constantize I got #<NoMethodError: undefined method `belongs_to' for Relatorio:Class>"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, belongs-to

I have a model:

```
class Relatorio < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :something
end
```

and

```
class ApplicationRecord < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.abstract_class = true
end
```

And I have this "before action" on super abstract Controller: "set_model_name":

```
def set_model_name
  @model_name ||= controller_name.classify
  @model_class ||= controller_name.classify.constantize
end
```

In the line "constantize" of "controller_name.classify.constantize" from the set_model_name I got this error:

```
#<NoMethodError: undefined method `belongs_to' for Relatorio:Class>"
```

But after change the model to to use "ActiveRecord::Base" instead of "ApplicationRecord" the problem did not occur anymore  :
  class Relatorio < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :something
  end

The problem is the use of "ActiveRecord::Base" is not the default and not is recommended to prevent monkey patching of "ActiveRecord".

What is the way to do "constantize" in a string changing that to Model, in cases where the model inherited from ActiveRecord ?

Thanks.

Comment: FWIW, you might consider using `safe_constantize`.

Comment: @nik]ckM Thanks. The "safe_constantize" can prevent the error but not solve the problem, because "nil" is returned. I really need a instance of Model.

Comment: I can't reproduce this by using `"relatorio".classify.constantize`. Are you sure your not causing the error by sloppyness? Try creating a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I could only think that this problem would happen if you have a classed called `Relatorio` which did not have `ActiveRecord::Base` in its inheritance chain. The code that you've got so far seems fine. Do you have an MCVE?

Comment: Hmm. I'll make the MCVE. But I think is another thing on the project breaking my inheritance.